# Ventana de Opciones

Tags: c#

Estoy buscando como hacer (que no se como se hace) que me salga un desplegable de opciones en un Formulario cuándo busco en un textbox para que pueda elegir la opción a medida que escribo el nombre de país. Os dejo un ejemplo de lo que digo por si no lo he explicado bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Se llama *autofill* y hay muchas formas de hacerlo. Supongo que incluso hay librerías enteras que lo hacen. Por otro lado, te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta no se ajusta al formato de [es.so]. Por ello podría terminar cerrada. Saludos

Comment: Gracias, le echaré un ojo.

Comment: Hola Jesus, podrias decir si la respuesta dada te resulto util, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que quieres hacer se llama autocompletamiento y se puede hacer tanto para **TextBox** como para **ComboBox**.

Lo que debes hacer es seleccionar tu **TextBox** y configurar las siguientes propiedades:

**AutoCompleteMode**: le das el valor **SuggestAppend**. Esta propiedad hace que cuando vayas escribiendo en el componente te vaya haciendo sugerencias de palabras semejantes y te permita seleccionar entre todas las palabras semejantes la que deseas.

**AutoCompleteSource**: le das el valor **CustomSource**, indicando que la fuente del autocompletamiento será de una fuente personalizada por el desarrollador.

Para que estas dos propiedades funcionen debes darle la lista de palabras que van a servir como fuente de datos para el autocompletamiento, esto se hace a través de la **propiedad AutoCompleteCustomSource**. Esta propiedad acepta un **arreglo de strings**(ojo con esto ya que esta propiedad no acepta listas ni otros tipos de colecciones o objetos, por lo que cualquiera sea la colección que tengas debes convertirla al tipo **arreglo de string**).

Si no estás trabajando con una base de datos esta propiedad la puedes llenar a través del mismo inspector de objetos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En caso de que estés trabajando con una base de datos, como tu información cambia constantemente, ya que vas a añadir, eliminar o actualizar países, pues debes llenar esta propiedad desde la misma **tabla países**.

Para ello vas al **evento OnLoad** de tu formulario y pones este código(solo si estás usando **EntityFramework** y **Linq**, sino debes hacer la consulta en **SQL** puro usando **DataTables** y **DataSets** cosa que imagino sepas hacer: **select NombrePais from paises**):

```
var arrayPaises = (from p in paises
                   select p.NombrePais).ToArray();

paisTextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(arrayPaises);
```

Aquí asumo que tu tabla se llama paises y que el campo de los nombres de los países se llama **NombrePais**.(En tu diseño eso puede variar).

Lo que se hace aquí es obtener de tu **tabla paises** todos los países para que sirvan de fuente de autocompletamiento, fíjate como solo selecciono la **propiedad NombrePais** que debe ser de tipo **string**, y convierto esa colección a array utilizando el **método ToArray**, devolviendo finalmente un **arreglo de string**.(Recuerda lo que te expliqué mas arriba).

Por último asigno a la **propiedad AutoCompleteCustomSource** la **variable arrayPaises**.

Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```